# Ionic External link from email to application (Deep Linking)

Tags: ionic-framework

I'm trying to add a **link from email**
that click on it **will open the application in the relevant page**.

I haven't found a solution for that yet.

If you do have any recommendation how to do that, i'll be glad to know.

Thanks.

**This is the scenario :**

1. user click forgot passowrd.
2. email is sent via server.
3. the email contains link for reset the password **(this is what i need)**
4. user click on the link an enter the reset password page on mobile application.

It's relevant to say that it should support All ionic platform (most important ios/ android)

Comment: Use deep link feature: http://developer.android.com/training/app-indexing/deep-linking.html. works for Android/iOS

Comment: @MaximShoustin but it based on Android what about iOS? shouldn't they have a solution for that on ionic platform ?

Comment: I'm not sure but i think this might be the solution : https://github.com/EddyVerbruggen/Custom-URL-scheme

Comment: for iOS should be easier to implement this.

Answer (score 1):

I agree with @LiadLivnat in the past I used [Custom-URL-scheme](https://github.com/EddyVerbruggen/Custom-URL-scheme).

Here is a snippets of code:

Consider you have some `run` with `reportAppLaunched` method:

```
app.run(function($rootScope){
 /* ... */

  $rootScope.reportAppLaunched = function(url) {
        $log.debug("App Launched Via Custom URL: " + url);

        $rootScope.$apply(function() {

            if (url.substring(0, 'mailto:'.length) === 'mailto:') {
                $rootScope.navigateTo('forgot_password_view', {action: url});
            }

        });
    };
}
```

Now this global function will be fired when, in my case, user opens contact list and clicks on some member. Android will ask with witch application you want to open this contact and you select . The method `handleOpenURL` is triggered and you can redirect to specific view in your application.

```
function handleOpenURL(url) {
    var body = document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0];
    var rootController = angular.element(body).scope();
    rootController.reportAppLaunched(url);
}
```

Hope it will help,

Comment: Thanks @maxim but the solution is missing how should the url should looks like, also who will call reportAppLaiunched? and why did you trim the mailto: url ?

Comment: `reportAppLaiunched ` you call from `handleOpenURL`.

Comment: The URL looks like: <appName>://path?foo=bar